# Where are my lost photos

Tags: google-plus-photos

I had a few years of photos on my phone. they were backed up onto google+. Google had gone into them and put some together making a video. My phone was recently reset but that should not have anything to do with google+. But yet my photos are not there from  and on. Just recent ones. Where did they go and how did it happen? Can I get them back?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking at 'Google Photos' app...Google had recently announced that they were no longer going to support g+ photo backup...but not to worry!! All your g+ backed up photos would've been shifted to Google Photos